# Android Kotlin Get WiFi Signal Strength in dBm

Tags: kotlin, wifi

I'm developing a Flutter app that requires getting WiFi Signal Strength in dBm. My Flutter app is using Android Kotlin and Android 12 with Android SDK 33

I found some sample code on the Internet (and Stackoverflow of course) but they seem to be deprecated in the latest Android version that I am using.

I also found SignalStrength in Android Docs at https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telephony/SignalStrength but I don't know how to use this, there is no sample code.

Could anyone help me to work with this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who is searching for the solution. Here is my working code:

```js
package com.example.myapp

import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.BatteryManager
import android.os.Build.VERSION
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
import android.net.Network
import android.net.TransportInfo
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo
import android.net.NetworkRequest
import android.util.Log

import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "myapp.flutter.dev"
    private var wifiSignalStrength: Int = 0

    val networkRequest: NetworkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder().addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI).build()

    val networkCallback = object: NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {}

        override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(network: Network, networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities) {
            val wifiInfo: WifiInfo = networkCapabilities.getTransportInfo() as WifiInfo
            wifiSignalStrength = wifiInfo.getRssi()
            Log.d("[log]", "wifiSignalStrength ${wifiSignalStrength}")
        }
    }

    val myRssiChangeReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
            val wifiManager = getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
            if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.S) {
                val wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo()
                wifiSignalStrength = wifiInfo.getRssi()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.S) {
            val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback) // For request
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback) // For listen
        }
        else {
            registerReceiver(myRssiChangeReceiver, IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION))
        }
        
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
            call, result ->
                if (call.method == "getWifiSignalStrength") {
                    result.success(wifiSignalStrength)
                }
                else {
                    result.notImplemented()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The core code is shown below.You can refer to the [NetStateUtils](https://github.com/SakurajimaMaii/Android-Vast-Extension/blob/develop/libraries/VastTools/src/main/kotlin/com/ave/vastgui/tools/utils/NetStateUtils.kt) I provided to get the complete code, which handles SDK compatibility and also handles wifi strength in VPN mode.

```kotlin
/**
 * Get wifi signal strength.
 *
 * Return [WIFIDBM.NOWIFICONNECT] when wifi is disconnected or unable or
 * return [WIFIDBM.UNSPECIFIED] when can't get the strength of wifi.
 *
 * When the [Build.VERSION.SDK_INT] is under [Build.VERSION_CODES.S],the
 * signal strength of [WIFIDBM.CURRENTDBM] is represented by
 * 0-4, otherwise the signal strength of [WIFIDBM.CURRENTDBM]
 * is represented by 0-[WifiManager.getMaxSignalLevel].
 *
 * @throws SecurityException Throw this exception if there is no
 *     ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission.
 * @since 0.5.3
 */
@JvmStatic
@kotlin.jvm.Throws(RuntimeException::class, SecurityException::class)
fun getWifiDBM(context: Context): WIFIDBM {
    if (!isWIFI(context)) return WIFIDBM.NOWIFICONNECT
    // See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConnectionInfo()
    // for the deprecate information.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            throw SecurityException("Please apply the permission ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.")
        }
        val wifiManager = context.getWifiManager()
        @Suppress("deprecation")
        val rssi = wifiManager.connectionInfo.rssi
        // Signal strength, 5 means the acquired signal strength value is within 5
        return WIFIDBM.CURRENTDBM(wifiManager.calculateSignalLevelImpl(rssi, 5))
    } else {
        val wifiManager = context.getWifiManager()
        val networkCapabilities = getNetworkCapabilities(context) ?: return WIFIDBM.UNSPECIFIED
        // Get wifi dbm when using vpn.
        // Must first check whether it is a VPN connection, otherwise an exception will
        // occur android.net.VpnTransportInfo cannot be cast to android.net.wifi.WifiInfo.
        if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)) {
            var rssi = 0
            val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                .build()
            val cm = context.getConnectivityManager()
            val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(
                    network: Network,
                    networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities
                ) {
                    rssi = (networkCapabilities.transportInfo as WifiInfo).rssi
                    cm.unregisterNetworkCallback(this)
                }
            }
            cm.registerNetworkCallback(request, networkCallback)
            return WIFIDBM.CURRENTDBM(wifiManager.calculateSignalLevelImpl(rssi, 5))
        }
        // Get wifi dbm when using wifi.
        else if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            val wifiInfo = networkCapabilities.transportInfo as WifiInfo
            return WIFIDBM.CURRENTDBM(wifiManager.calculateSignalLevelImpl(wifiInfo.rssi, 5))
        } else return WIFIDBM.UNSPECIFIED
    }
}
```

Comment: showing how to use it to solve the problem would increase the long term value of this answer.